# Java filter works with one predicate but not with another

Tags: java, filter, predicate

Help! This doesn't make the slightest kind of sense.
I have a Java Collection and a method that filters this collection.

```
public void filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    for (MyItem<T> item=head; item!=null; item=item.next) {
        if(predicate.test(item.key))
            remove(item.key);
        item = item.next;
    }
}
```

Then, when I run it with one predicate, it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MySet<Integer> set = new MySet<>();
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        set.add(i);
    }
    set.filter(x->x%2==0);
    MyItem<Integer> item = set.head;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        System.out.println(item.key);
        item = item.next;
    }
}
```

It correctly outputs all the uneven numbers from 1 to 19.
If I change the predicate to `x->x%2==1`, however, it doesn't output all the even numbers from 0 to 18, it outputs **all** numbers from 0 to 9.

Why is this even possible???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 times `item=item.next`, once in the for loop declaration and once inside. So you skip half of the items.

```
for (MyItem<T> item=head; item!=null; item=item.next) {
    if(predicate.test(item.key))
        remove(item.key);
    // item = item.next; ???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely comes from the fact that you skip every second element in your loop inside of `filter` method. You call `item = item.next` twice in there, as an "increment" of the loop (3rd part of the loop definition) and then at the end of each iteration.

```
public void filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    for (MyItem<T> item=head; item!=null; item=item.next) { //<- here
        if(predicate.test(item.key))
            remove(item.key);
        item = item.next; //<- here
    }
}
```

Remove either of those, preferably in the last line, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, I realise now how dumb my question was!